# Why is my reCAPTCHA always wrong? (incorrect-captcha-sol)

Tags: asp.net, recaptcha

I have a reCAPTCHA on my asp.net page (using the RecaptchaControl from Google : https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/aspnet). But it always returns false when I try to validate it.

I have checked with fiddler the values being posted and double-checked everything, but it continues to fail.

Also, if it matters, I am doing the check in the control of a button, not in a Page Load.

Comment: Please provide the code that you're implementing, so we cant help in a better way

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, it appears that, while everything will look right in the validation request, if you validate the RecaptchaControl in a click event, it will always return false. (Even if you don't try to assign or use the IsValid property of the RecatpchaControl.)

While it is not trying to assign that property of the control (which should have happened before your click event), it seems to always fail inside a control's event.

Try moving your validation to Page Load or any Page event that fires before click handler and it will likely work.